# Strip Time From Pandas Datetime Excel DateOffset

Tags: python, excel, pandas, datetime, offset

so i  import an excel sheet that has a field 'DT RECD' which formats the date as mm/dd/yy which is column 7 within the excel sheet,  i import my Data like so:

```
import datetime
import pandas as pd


excel_workbook = 'ExcelSheet.xlsx'
sheet1 = pd.read_excel(excel_workbook,
                       sheet_name='Sheet1',
                       keep_default_na= False,
                       index_col=0,
                       parse_dates=['DT RECD'])
sheet1['DT RECD'] = pd.to_datetime(sheet1['DT RECD'])
```

when i print the data it looks like this, which is perfect for what i need to do.

```
DT RECD     LOT Number  FNISH                
2008-07-23     471359     AL  
2018-05-18   71378301     CR  
2018-05-18     713787     CR  
2018-11-09   74219202     CR
```

then i need to filter this data on date "1 year and over to 2 year mark" "2 years and over to 3 year mark" and so on.  so i create my date for today and 1,2,3,4,.... years out and apply an offset from pandas like so:

```
today = datetime.date.today()
oneYear = today - pd.DateOffset(years=1)
#oneYear = today - datetime.timedelta(years=1) <- did not work 
twoYear = today - pd.DateOffset(years=2)
```

Now here is the problem  my dates have 00:00:00 within them

```
2021-03-03
2020-03-03 00:00:00
2019-03-03 00:00:00
```

I am trying to take the data between year one and year two and post to new sheet, Like this:

```
YearOne = sheet1[sheet1['DT RECD'].between(oneYear, twoYear)]
```

I am getting an empty data-set when I print YearOne - this is "index_col=0"
if i print sheet1 the data is all there.

```
Empty DataFrame
Columns: [...,THICKNESS,...,DT RECD, 
Index: []
```

I am lost on how to pull the one-two year of data.

this is how i write back to excel as well

```
writer = pd.ExcelWriter('ExcelSheet.xlsx', mode='a', engine='openpyxl')
YearOne.to_excel(writer, '1 Year')
```

When i set Index_col=7 which is the "DT RECD" column i get an error:

```
sheet1 = pd.read_excel(excel_workbook,
                       sheet_name='Sheet1',
                       keep_default_na= False,
                       index_col=7,
                       parse_dates=['DT RECD'])
```

I get this error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "...\site-packages\pandas\core\indexes\base.py", line 3080, in get_loc
    return self._engine.get_loc(casted_key)
  File "pandas\_libs\index.pyx", line 70, in pandas._libs.index.IndexEngine.get_loc
  File "pandas\_libs\index.pyx", line 101, in pandas._libs.index.IndexEngine.get_loc
  File "pandas\_libs\hashtable_class_helper.pxi", line 4554, in pandas._libs.hashtable.PyObjectHashTable.get_item
  File "pandas\_libs\hashtable_class_helper.pxi", line 4562, in pandas._libs.hashtable.PyObjectHashTable.get_item
KeyError: 'DT RECD'

The above exception was the direct cause of the following exception:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\steven\PycharmProjects\Test\venv\Foreach Loop Panda.py", line 11, in <module>
    sheet1['DT RECD'] = pd.to_datetime(sheet1['DT RECD'])
  File "C:\Users\steven\PycharmProjects\Test\venv\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\frame.py", line 3024, in __getitem__
    indexer = self.columns.get_loc(key)
  File "C:\Users\steven\PycharmProjects\Test\venv\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\indexes\base.py", line 3082, in get_loc
    raise KeyError(key) from err
KeyError: 'DT RECD'
```

if the Index_col=0 i get no errors but there is no data within the "YearOne" Data when trying to get data between 2 years.

Comment: in principal pandas makes not difference between date and time, these are always stored *together* (it's just a matter of display if the time is shown or not). this is not the source of your problem. then: which line exactly is throwing the error? could you post the full traceback?

Comment: Typo on the output on my end, i will fix

Comment: not sure why you mean by Trace-back, but i get no errors if i set index_col=0. but there is and empty data-frame which leads be to believe the 00:00:00 is causing the data frame "YearOne" to be empty. cause i do a print(sheet1) all the data is there.